# Azure Data Factory does not update properly when changes are pushed from a branch

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm doing all of my configuration locally, and pushing the json files.

I'm having all kinds of issues with ADF not noticing the changes, or only noticing some of the changes.

I changed the linked service name, for example, pushed the branch, and then in ADF tried to trigger a deploy. I got errors with the old service name.

I waited a while, changed branch back and forth in ADF, hoping it would refresh somehow. After a while I tried again and it partially worked, it got further into it but then the same issue occurred, one of the table migrations I set up gave a credentials error and I could see it was trying to use the wrong connection again.

I double checked the JSON and it was definitely using the wrong connection.

This is a recurring issue. I've tried hitting the button to force changes from the branch but it says nothing to update. The problem is recurring a lot and is very annoying.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we create a pull request from local branch, make sure that branch is the newest branch that is just made to push the changes.

You can Work on the development in your local branch, but meanwhile there can be people working on other branches and pushing there changes which can conflict with your local branch.

So download the pipeline suppport zip file which is developed and tested and copy it in a new branch and push your changes and delete the new branch. This will avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My work around is to delete old configs temporary, leave only the new config there, and run the pipeline.

After the pipeline is ran, I then added everything back.

I'm pretty sure that it's not a branch issue.